# convert xldate to python datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem converting excel xldate to python datetime with the following code. Is this the right way to convert?

```
import xlrd
from datetime import datetime

book = xlrd.open_workbook("a.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for rx in range(1,sh.nrows):
    a = sh.row(rx)
    print a  
    year, month, day, hour, minute = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a[0], book.datemode)
    py_date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
```

---

a is printed -->

```
   [xldate:40544.0, number:0.0, number:75.49847785316135, number:75.6401124106301]
```

---

The below error is shown

```
  year, month, day, hour, minute = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a[0], book.datemode)

  File "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.py", line 67, in xldate_as_tuple
    xldays = int(xldate)
  TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cell'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `a[0].value`?

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Don't out answers in the question; you can answer your own question if you figure it out in the meantime.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`a[0]` is a [`xlrd.Cell`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Cell-class), so you need to use `a[0].value` to access the cell content.

Also, you can't unpack to `year, month, day, hour, minute` because there are more than five values in the tuple produced (what about `second`?) However, you can avoid that by using tuple unpacking (see e.g. [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761)) instead of the temporary variables:

```
py_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a[0].value,
                                                  book.datemode))
```

Answer (score 22):

@jonrsharpe's accepted answer works well. But this is cleaner:

```
py_date = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(a[0].value, book.datemode)
```