# Unable to read date time values in the correct format from excel file and save it in a database using python

Tags: python, sql, excel, datetime, cell-formatting

I have a piece of code in python that reads from a excel file and saves into redshift database.

```
import psycopg2
def from_redshift():
    book = xlrd.open_workbook("excelfile.xlsx")
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='dbname', host='something.com', port=portnum, user='username', password='password')
    cursor=con.cursor()

    query = """INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3, start_date, update_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        col1 = sheet.cell(r,0).value
        col2 = sheet.cell(r,1).value

        col3 = sheet.cell(r,2).value
        start_date     = sheet.cell(r,3).value
        update_date = sheet.cell(r,4).value

        # Assign values from each row
        values = (col1, col2, col3, start_date, update_date)

        # Execute sql Query
        cursor.execute(query, values)
        print("Executed")
    # Close the cursor
    cursor.close()
```

The code works fine in reading and inserting into the database, but my question is that the '`start_date`' and the '`update_date`' fields are of `datetime` in the database, so when I try to insert then, it gives me error that the values from these two columns are not in the right format, and when I changed these two columns to `varchar` in the database, it inserts these values are some weird number like `23.12345` (something like that).

The values in these two column look like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:[SS]` (custom format).

How do I get these date time values in the database correctly?

```
    # Commit the transaction
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010455/convert-xldate-to-python-datetime

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727916/how-to-use-xlrd-xldate-as-tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation on xlrd](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html)

To read the date values you can use the [xldate_as_tuple function](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function)

Because the dates are stored as numbers within the excel file format

I have't tested this, but with your code:

```
def from_redshift():
    book = xlrd.open_workbook("excelfile.xlsx")
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        start_date     = xldate_as_tuple(sheet.cell(r,3).value, book.datemode)
        start_date = datetime.datetime(*start_date)
```

BTW, if your method name is any indication of what you are doing. If you are loading this data into AWS Redshift, copying from a CSV file is always faster, easier and generally recommended over executing inserts from excel data like this.

Comment: Please give me an example usage of this